# How can I change data into my form when I choose a dropdown list symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to make a dropdown list of some inventory. For example I have two field in my database

```
 columnA | columnB | columnC    
 ____________________________
| A      |   3     | 2       |
| B      |   1     | 5       |
```

So when I created my form I put columnA like a dropdown list and the another fields are input type.

Then I would like when change my selection in the dropdown list change values showed in the another fields.

By the way, I was looking the [Generate Forms Based on user Data](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-user-data). I think the solution could be this.

I hope your help. Grettings

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you trigger an ajax function when you change the value in your first dropdown list. This function will interogate a controller wich will make the database request. And at last, on success your ajax function will populate your second dropdown with the returned value.